# How can I run command to install software without sudo?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, sudo, skype

I am trying to install Skype using the command

```
dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

It gives me a error:

```
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

How can I assign superuser privilege to current user so that I can run command without sudo?

Here is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

When I run the following command

```
sudo adduser ehsaan sudo
```

it gives an error:

```
The user `ehsaan' is already a member of `sudo'.
```

Comment: i want to install without sudo.  sudo make some problem with vagrant installation

Comment: You don't?  Either you use "sudo" and provide the password or you let the admin of the system install it for you. Mind though: what you want here is NOT going to work without installing i386 support on your system (it is not likely it has it). And installing skype with sudo has no relation to vagrant.

Comment: Skype is just a example. I have to install  a lot of others

Comment: So? Do as we all do: use "sudo". It is the intended method of installing in Ubuntu.  Alternative: `sudo -i` , provide password and then you can skip the "sudo" in the commands.  But that technically is still using sudo to install software.

Answer (score 0):

Sudo is required to make edits to the system files, unless you log in as root. It is not possible to my knowledge.